# Group of invaders

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

> **Across**
>   4. Singer Tom serves food with delays (5)
>   7. Told secrets upon deep rambling (6,2)
>   10. Group of invaders to be at the French shores, finally? (7)
>   11. Pass around the tales to sportspeople (8)
>   12. Originally comic actress, ultimately Marilyn could dance... (3-3)
>   14/21. ...or, back in the 50s, sing notes freely for a band (3,7,6)
>   19. A member of the Allies gets behind Axis meeting point in a creative manner (10)
>   22. Non-essential album with instant message about nu metal (8)
>   24. Noodle dish had a tip out (3,4)
>   25. Organ grinder's partner broke China cup (8)
>   26. A professor can have this speaking voice, sometimes dramatic (5)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Ruler's family central to destroy Al tyrannically (7)
>   2. One raised anger after wager, which is something to avoid (4,5)
>   3. Underground video service abandoned by second person (4)
>   5. Playing roles and casting dancing performers, eventually to be dropped (6)
>   6. The darkening soul of a Hubbard follower (6)
>   8. Repeated sounds from case of electric tools (6)
>   9. Casino performer's escape caught by private eye? (5)
>   13. An old New York rodent cuts tail to be unidentified (9)
>   15. Record-length zero gravity (3)
>   16. Avid tweeter owns large Dodge (6)
>   17. State mayors essentially behind West Wing replacing woman with man (7)
>   18. A bully is not stressed at all (2,4)
>   19. Radio network covering boxing combination (3-3)
>   20. Newton is repeatedly a workaholic, in the end (5)
>   23. Man in parliament (4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

across

> 4 waits 7 opened up 10 beatles 11 athletes 12 can can 14/21 the rolling stones 19 originally  22 aluminum 24 pad thai 25 capuchin 26 tenor

explanations

> 4 tom waits is a singer
>  7 upon deep anagram
>  10 be at le(fr) shore**s**
>  11 the tales anagram
>  12 **c**omic **a**ctress marily**n**
>  14 or backwards, l = 50 x 2, sing notes anagram
>  19 origin (axis point) ally
>  22 alum with mi and nu inside
>  24 had a tip anagram
>  25 china cup anagram
>  26 homophone of tenure

down

> 1 royalty 2 bete noire 3 tube 5 acting 6 thetan 8 echoes 9 pesci 13 anonymous 15 log 16 flinch 17 wyoming 18 at ease 19 one two 20 isaac 23 liam

explanations

> 1 dest**royalty**ranically
>  2 one in reverse after bet and ire
>  3 you tube without you
>  5 casting anagram without last letter of performers
>  6 tanning = darkening
>  8 ec hoes
>  9 p esc i
>  13 an o ny mous(e)
>  15 **l**ength o **g**ravity
>  16 f l inch finch + l
>  17 w yo wing becomes ming
>  18 a tease
>  20 is a a workaholi**c**
>  23 par**liam**ent